# How to convert raw string to variable (variable --> $variable)?

Tags: linux, string, perl, variables

How to convert string to variable (string variable --> $variable)?

Or a list of variables delimited by commas then convert to actual variables.

I have 2 files:

- column names file
- rows file

I need to match a whole row from the rows file based on a string, and name each row based from the column names file.

Example:

#### COLUMN NAMES FILE content

```
name,age,gender
```

#### ROWS FILE content

```
mar,44,m
rich,49,m
glenn,22,m
```

Now I have a variable string `$who = 'glenn'`

I will first match it on the *ROWS FILE*.

Then I need to name its matched contents with an actual variable with its name based on the *COLUMN NAMES FILE*.

Output:

```
$name = 'glenn';
$age = 22;
$gender = 'm';
```

I need something that dynamically changes, creating the needed variables and contents automatically by only updating the content files.

Comment: Okay, so if you achieve this, how will you know what variable names to use in the rest of your Perl code?

Comment: @Borodin , I am building a universal/standard module at the company where I am working (called using require). Since this will be a module, there will expectations like what are the available variable. And for me not to worry, I will follow the SOLID principle, I can only add but not modify the expected available variables. Thanks for asking. Let me know if I can answer any other questions...

Comment: It's still a terrible idea to crap all over your namespace like this. What if someone creates a column called `/`? Or `0`? Or `^I`? You'll create some HORRIFIC bugs that will be an absolute horror to trace.

Comment: @Sobrique don't worry, "IT WON'T HAPPEN". Because the column names I am planning to create are based from a ora sql table, which is a production table.

Answer (score 9):

What you're asking for, is not what you want. This is a bad idea for many many reasons, but they're outlined here: http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html

What you need for this is a hash, and specifically a [slice](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices).

It works a bit like this:

```
my @header = qw ( A B C );
my @values = qw ( X Y Z );
my %combined;
@combined{@header} = @values; 
print Dumper \%combined;
```

Gives:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'C' => 'Z',
          'A' => 'X',
          'B' => 'Y'
        };
```

(NB: Hashes are explicitly UNORDERED, so you get a random sequence each time you print. That's by design, because they're supposed to be accessed via keys anyway)

So with your data:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all'; 

open ( my $cols, '<', 'cols_file.txt') or die $!;
chomp ( my @cols = split /,/, <$cols> ); #just reads first line. 
close ( $cols );
open ( my $rows, '<', 'rows_file.txt' ) or die $!; 
while ( <$rows> ) {
    chomp;
    my %this_row;
    @this_row{@cols} = split /,/;
    push ( @all_rows, \%this_row );
}
close ( $rows );

print Dumper \@all_rows;
```

You can then access individual elements from rows e.g.:

```
foreach my $row ( @all_rows ) {
    print $row -> {name},"\n";
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very very very very MUCH! You made my day! It worked like charm! :D I am so glad someone like you answered my question! Thank you so much once again. I have achieved what I need! :)